# Caesar cipher shifts by two letters instead of one

Tags: python

I want to make a Caesar cipher, but it seems like from my code, the letters shift 2 letters up. For example if the letter is a it will output `c` not `b`.

```
import collections

import string

def caesar(rotate):

  upper = collections.deque(string.ascii_uppercase)

  upper.rotate(1)
  upper = ''.join(list(upper))

  return rotate.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, upper))

code = input('Secret message: ')


print (caesar(code))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually getting `z` for an input of `a` when I run this. This is because the line `return rotate.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, upper))` maps `string.ascii_uppercase` to `upper` or `"ABC...Z"` to `"ZAB...Y"`, giving you a shift of one character to the left instead of to the right. You'll get the right shift I think your looking for by switching the order of arguments to `return rotate.translate(str.maketrans(upper, string.ascii_uppercase))`.